# Traverse an array recursively

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive method that receives an array and traverse it like with a loop, but without a loop.

Couldn't find a way to make an index, and increase each time I call the method.

Comment: Share any code which you have tried? and Ask if you are stuck with something.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function f(array,index) make it do something with array[index] and return function(array,index+1). Finally, to start it off call function(array,0). If there are any variables or state you are building up over the course of the recursive function, also pass it via the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark, but

```
public void printMyArray (String[] test, int index) {
    // verify the index isn't too large
        // Grab a value and do something with it.
}
```

Edit: As stated above, you basically just need to run through each value in the array. The easiest is really carrying over an index value (in my opinion).

Comment: This question is from a homework. In order to answer homework questions, we **must** not provide a direct answer, instead **guide** OP to find the solution. Read the other answer to understand what this means.

Comment: IMO it has too much light since it shows the signature of the method to use.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't make myself clear. No problem doing it with an index recived, but I have only an array recived.

Comment: @Rogue - thanks a lot man, your one line "The easiest is really carrying over an index value (in my opinion)." cleared a lot of concepts on me regarding recursion in arrays. Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem, glad it was helpful.